# Query to map field title by field id in Mongo DB result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections in mongo db named as "**Form**" and "**FormData**".

**Form Collection** - It has basic structure of form. It holds all Fields and their details
**FormData Collection** - It has data of the form by each field which was mapped with Field ID and Value.

> Form Collection Data:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e3c27bf1ef77236945ef07b"),
  "Fields":[
     {
        "FieldID": "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b",
        "Title": "Phone"
     },
     {
        "FieldID": "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03c",
        "Title": "Email"
     }
  ]
}
```

**Form Collection Data:**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e3c27bf1ef77236945ef07b"),
  "Data":[
     {
        "FieldID": "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03b",
        "Value": "0000000"
     },
     {
        "FieldID": "e8efd0b0-9d10-4584-bb11-5b24f189c03c",
        "Value": "00000@mail.com"
     }
  ]
}
```

Now I need results like below merge both Form and FormData collections by Field Id,

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e3c27bf1ef77236945ef07b"),
  "Data":
  {
     "Phone": "0000000",
     "Email": "00000@mail.com"
  }      
}
```

Can any one help me to get this above output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have the answer in your [newer, nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148418/change-element-name-from-the-result-set-of-mongo-db-query).

Comment: Thanks @ray I am checking on that., Will update you.,